# Anonymous Function with changing array size

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

I have the following code to solve some ordinary differential equation(ODE). In order to relieve myself of the burden of typing a long expression in each iteration of the for loop I decided to define an `anonymous function`. When I defined the anonymous function before initializing **x** vector it turned out an error since it used the elements of the vector **x**   in calculations. The anonymous function is as follows:

```
fnc = @(i) (-100 * (x(i) - cos(h * t(i))) - sin(h * t(i)));
```

In order to resolve the problem I initialized all elements of x to be zeros beforehand to avoid it complaining as follows:

```
Undefined function 'x' for input
arguments of type 'double'.
```

However, it turned out to mess up with solution depending on where I put the anonymous function. What may be the reason for this behaviour? My code can be found below, you can see the commented out regions to see where I tried to implement the anonymous function.

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;
t_s = 0; % Starting time 
t_f = 1; % Finishing time
h = 0.2; % Time step 
t = t_s:h:t_f;
N = (t_f - t_s) / h; % Number of time steps (excluding initial points)
% x = zeros(1, N + 1);
fnc = @(i) (-100 * (x(i) - cos(h * t(i))) - sin(h * t(i)));
x(1) = 1; % Initial condition given in the problem
x(2) = x(1) + h * fnc(1);
for in = 3:N+1
%    fnc = @(i) (-100 * (x(i) - cos(h * t(i))) - sin(h * t(i)));
   x(in) =  x(in - 1) + (3 / 2) * h * fnc(in - 1) + (-1 / 2) * h * fnc(in - 2); 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `x` is "hardwired" into the anonymous function when you create it. The function internally stores the value that `x` has at that time, and will always use that. Subsequent changes to `x` have no effect on the function. See this example [from the documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621):

> For example, create a function handle to an anonymous function that requires coefficients `a`, `b`, and `c`.
>
> `a = 1.3;`
>   `b = .2;`
>   `c = 30;`
>   `parabola = @(x) a*x.^2 + b*x + c;`
>
> Because `a`, `b`, and `c`  are available at the time you create `parabola`, the function handle includes those values. The values persist within the function handle even if you clear the variables:
>
> `clear a b c` 
>   `x = 1;` 
>   `y = parabola(x)` 
>   `y =` 
>   `31.5000`

You can check which values are stored by the function using [`functions`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html). For example:

```
>> x = [1 2 3 4];
>> fnc = @(i) (-100 * (x(i) - cos(h * t(i))) - sin(h * t(i)));
>> f = functions(fnc)
f = 
     function: '@(i)(-100*(x(i)-cos(h*t(i)))-sin(h*t(i)))'
         type: 'anonymous'
         file: ''
    workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
>> f.workspace{1}
ans = 
    x: [1 2 3 4]
```

If you need the function to depend on `x`, put `x` as an additional input (and call the function with the desired `x` each time):

```
fnc = @(i,x) (-100 * (x(i) - cos(h * t(i))) - sin(h * t(i)));
```

Comment: Well thanks that was very explanatory can I define this function before defining or initializing `x` by the way?

Comment: @Vesnog No, unless `x` is declared as an input: `fnc = @(i,x)...` All variables that are not inputs to the function need to be defined, and their values are fixed regarding the function

Comment: Okay I understood now thanks for your effort, I appreciate it.